# Internet Explorer issue setting filter="url(...)" attribute using javascript: adding extra quotes

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, svg-filters

I'm currently trying to add `filter="url(...)"` attributes as `svg` fallback in internet explorer 10-11. However, when I'm doing it the browser (IE) apparently adds extra quotes, making the attribute look as below and making it invalid:

`filter="url("#shadow")"`

The same issue only occus when applying the outer quotes as single quotes such as: `filter='url(#shadow)'` - which then again results in: `filter="url("#shadow)")"`

**Is there any workaround for this?**

An example for reproduction can be seen below:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#icon").attr("filter", 'url(#shadow)');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg>
<defs>
<filter id="shadow" height="130%" width="130%">
  <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="0"></feGaussianBlur>
  <feOffset dx="3" dy="3" result="offsetblur"></feOffset>
  <feFlood flood-color="red" flood-opacity="1"></feFlood>
  <feComposite in2="offsetblur" operator="in"></feComposite>
  <feMerge>
  <feMergeNode></feMergeNode>
  <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"></feMergeNode>
  </feMerge>
 </filter>
 </defs>
 </svg>
<svg id="icon" viewBox="0 0 16 28" width="100px" height="100px">
<path d="M11.5 9c0 0.266-0.234 0.5-0.5 0.5s-0.5-0.234-0.5-0.5c0-1.078-1.672-1.5-2.5-1.5-0.266 0-0.5-0.234-0.5-0.5s0.234-0.5 0.5-0.5c1.453 0 3.5 0.766 3.5 2.5zM14 9c0-3.125-3.172-5-6-5s-6 1.875-6 5c0 1 0.406 2.047 1.062 2.812 0.297 0.344 0.641 0.672 0.953 1.031 1.109 1.328 2.047 2.891 2.203 4.656h3.563c0.156-1.766 1.094-3.328 2.203-4.656 0.313-0.359 0.656-0.688 0.953-1.031 0.656-0.766 1.062-1.813 1.062-2.812zM16 9c0 1.609-0.531 3-1.609 4.188s-2.5 2.859-2.625 4.531c0.453 0.266 0.734 0.766 0.734 1.281 0 0.375-0.141 0.734-0.391 1 0.25 0.266 0.391 0.625 0.391 1 0 0.516-0.266 0.984-0.703 1.266 0.125 0.219 0.203 0.484 0.203 0.734 0 1.016-0.797 1.5-1.703 1.5-0.406 0.906-1.313 1.5-2.297 1.5s-1.891-0.594-2.297-1.5c-0.906 0-1.703-0.484-1.703-1.5 0-0.25 0.078-0.516 0.203-0.734-0.438-0.281-0.703-0.75-0.703-1.266 0-0.375 0.141-0.734 0.391-1-0.25-0.266-0.391-0.625-0.391-1 0-0.516 0.281-1.016 0.734-1.281-0.125-1.672-1.547-3.344-2.625-4.531s-1.609-2.578-1.609-4.188c0-4.25 4.047-7 8-7s8 2.75 8 7z"></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: Have you tried to provide quotes around the value inside url() to begin with? `.attr("filter", 'url("#shadow")')`, or the other way around? Maybe that'll keep IE from trying to add them itself - and picking the wrong ones while doing so.

Comment: @CBroe sadly that doesn't work either

Comment: What if you go around jQuery's `.attr` method, and try "old school", `$("#icon")[0].filter = "url(#shadow)";` ...?

Comment: @CBroe that method doesn't actually set the attribute, or am I missing something? PS. I've already tried `$("#icon")[0].setAttribute(...)` and that didnt work either

Comment: Well it works for a lot of common attributes at least, so worth a try I thought. Hm, if old school don't work, let's take it up a notch to "hard core" maybe? `outerHTML` does not seem to work on SVG elements as quick research suggests - but you could try and put the `svg` into a `div` element first, and then use that one's `innerHTML` to replace the first part, `<svg` with `<svg filter="..."` ...? That would get as close to  having it in the initial HTML to begin with as you could get, I suppose. Leave it all to the parser basically, and hope it doesn't mess up as well.

Comment: If the div would interrupt the rest of your layout/setup, you could create it in the script only, append the svg element to it, do the magic, put the svg back into the document and throw away the div ... Only cave-at, if you had any event handlers bound to the SVG before already or similar, you'd lose those.

Comment: Thank you for the ideas @CBroe however I figured out that I Was applying filter to the `svg` element when it Should have been the `use` element in order for IE to show it. I even wrote a question About this behaviour some time Ago and then apparently forgot About it again - my apologies ;)